# Mollifier function of $f(x)=|x|$ in Scilab.

Tags: analysis, smooth-functions

[image]

Hello. I am trying to graph the different approximations of the function $f(x)=|x|$ by convolutions with the standard Mollifier function. However, my code doesn't output the correct graph. What is wrong in the code? (This question is motivated by a topic I made [Application of Mollifier function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636609/application-of-mollifier-function/4636650?noredirect=1#comment9784387_4636650))

Actualization 1: I tried the following code in Scilab but it doesn't work. error appears. Attached image.

```
x = -1:0.1:1;
f = (x > -1 & x < 1).*abs(x)+(x <= -1 | x >= 1).*0;
phi = (x > -1 & x < 1).*(exp(1/(x.^2-1))/sqrt(2*%pi))+(x <= -1 | x >= 1).*0;
y = conv(f, phi, 'same') * 0.1;
plot(x, f, 'b', x, y, 'r');
legend('f(x)', 'Convolution f * phi');
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that your function is not big enough. You are now kind-of taking the convolution of $f(x)=\begin{cases}|x|&-1<x<1\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$ instead of $|x|$. Try taking the range of $x$ to be at least "width of mollifier" bigger than the part you want to plot

Comment: I tried and couldn't. I will put the code of which gives me error.